# Error for a php script and phar file `ERROR: manifest length read was "11636290" should be "182976516"`

Tags: php, phar

Ive got a php script that that is essentially a GUI for for editing and saving names and phone numbers to an XML file on a server.

The script itself contains an index.php with the following, a directory for storing the XML and a .phar file, the index.php references both as follows :

```
<?php 

$properties = array(
    'directory' => __DIR__ . '/pb',         // default directory of the XML files
    'defaultFileName' => 'contacts.xml',    // default phonebook file
    'debug' => false,                        // debug mode
);

// Don't edit below this line
$properties['rootDirectory'] = __DIR__.'/';
require_once 'yealink-phonebook.phar';
```

When i got to the root of the directory where the index.php is housed i get the following error

`ERROR: manifest length read was "11636290" should be "182976516"`

I have a search around but couldnt find any info on the particular error, any idea what it means and how it can be resolved ?

For reference the script is part of this repo : https://github.com/octivi/yealink-phonebook.

Ive noticed that on this server its running php 5.2.17 - could that be causing the issue ?

**UPDATE** i think the 11636290 part of the error may be related to the size of the phar file which is 11636290 bytes. eg. 11.6mb - not sure how that helps though but noticed they where the same.

Comment: @DamienSugden Thanks ive double checked but yealink-phonebook.phar, index.php and /pb folder and in the same root directory

Comment: Your phar file is invalid, rebuild or re-download it.

Comment: Thanks @miken32 i upgraded the PHP version to 5.3.x and it now seems to work

Comment: PHP 5.3 has been unsupported for more than 5 years, you should not be using it. 7.0 is the current version.

Comment: I really can't stress how bad an idea using 5.3 is!

Comment: @miken32 unfortunatly all this host has is 5.2 and 5.3

Answer (score 1):

i had to enable phar **extension** in php settings

Comment: Please give more details